# responsive image source shuffling technique - not working in Chrome 33

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

I followed this technique for responsive image : http://www.jordanm.co.uk/lab/sourceshuffling and it used to work well on chrome, safari , firefox. But now when I test with Chrome 33 , it fails. Even the demo from the author doesn't work anymore with Chrome 33. I can't figure out what the problem is. if anyone can help to find the right direction please.